# Use regex to toggle "asc" <--> "desc" without using MatchEvaluator

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string of column sort orders, e.g. `string sortOrders = "foo asc, bar desc, hi desc";`.

I want to take in an input column name, and if it's already in our sort order string, toggle the direction of the sort.  This is easy enough with

```
string sortOrders = "foo asc, bar desc, hi desc";
string colName = "bar";
Regex.Replace(sortOrders, 
              colName + " (desc|asc)", 
              m => colName + " " + (m.Groups[1].Value == "desc" ? "asc" : "desc"));

// result: "foo asc, bar asc, hi desc"
```

Is there a simpler version that doesn't use a `MatchEvaluator`?

Comment: You do realize that "bar" would also match "foobar".  You probably want `\b` before colName in the regular expression to avoid that situation.

Comment: Good point!  Thanks!